# Creating an instance from an instance of a class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

This question comes form the following link
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Specifically, **Example #5 Creating new objects**

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;
var_dump($obj1 !== $obj2); //bool(true)
```

I can't figure out why it is okay or logical to use the `new` operator on `$obj1` to create `$obj2` when `$obj1` is clearly just an **object**, not a **class**?

I have been trying to find reference on this topic, but could not find one.

Thanks

Comment: Probably PHP do some conversion to find the class of that object, and then create a new instance. Need to check PHP source code. The same doesn't applies to some languages like Java.

Comment: If that is the case, it is very counter-intuitive. And that was a documentation on basics.

Comment: Is it? What would be "intuitive"?

Comment: I honestly can't think of any scenario where I've needed to use this feature, but I can easily imagine how it could be useful in a polymorphic system, particularly if your objects are immutable and the only way to change them is to create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why they added a possibility to create a new object with an instance of the class but the instance is used as a class in this case. You even can pass constructor arguments. Try this code:

```
class Waat {
    public $message;

    public function __construct($message )
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
}

$w1 = new Waat('hello');
$w2 = new $w1('world');

echo $w1->message . ' ' . $w2->message;
```

It outputs:

```
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks. I have actually tested it, and it indeed is used like a class.